# Overflow error in np.exp function for a curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, physics, gaussian

I'm trying to fit a combined gaussian using the following code:

```py
def curve_f(x,a,b,c,d,e,f):
  return (a*np.exp(((x-b)**2)/(2*-c**2)))+(d*np.exp(((x-e)**2)/(2*f**2)))
```

The problem is that when I put this function in `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` using my data, I get the following warning:

```py
<ipython-input-27-1baee2b89bf1>:2: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return (a*np.exp(((x-b)**2)/(2*-c**2)))+(d*np.exp(((x-e)**2)/(2*f**2)))
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:862: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)
```

I tried putting my data in float128 but it didn't work.

Here is what my data looks like.

[image]

Here is a sample of the data (this is for y axis):
[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   -1 -110 1290   33    0
0    0    0    0   -1    1    1    2    2    0   -1   -2   -1    1
1    1    2    2    2    4   -3    5    5    7    3   10    3   11
10    4   16   13   32   23   21   23   37   42   42   43   56   62
41   56   71   59   61   84   82   76   73   78   73   69   84   85
74   65   75   59   74   73   76   74   60   95   63   91   85   82
73   72   76   82   71   85   71   60   53   71   84   95   83   50
88   63   76   68   81   73   80   60   89   78   76   86   73   99
91   94  104   98  114  117  110  122  104  106  121  135  130  161
146  133  172  145  186  202  222  216  205  200  234  219  231  265
269  266  296  286  304  303  325  319  381  328  362  370  339  360
423  405  368  400  411  416  448  454  453  468  480  427  433  490
471  505  500  442  483  482  462  436  457  483  435  431  432  416
410  438  402  422  387  403  366  371  369  339  341  306  327  331
310  296  277  259  268  228  214  225  234  204  208  205  205  176
168  190  192  142  161  126  107  122  112   86  107   92   90   89
78   82   59   69   67   57   34   42   46   44   35   36   37   29
28   29   25   20   20   18   20   17    8   22   12    9    9    7
13    8   11    5    5   14    5    3    6    4    6    9    2    5
5    2    4    5    8    7    5    1    4    3    2    6   -1    3
3    3    2    3    2    3    1    1    2    0    1    2    3    0
1    0    5    3    2    1    1    2    2    0    4    3    1    2
2    4    2    4    0    4    1    2    1    1    1    1    0    2
-1    2    1    1    1    4    0    4    2    3    0   -1    1    3
1    2    0    2    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1
1    0    0    1    2    2    0    3    2    1    1    1    0    0
1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    1    2    0    1   -1    2
1    1    2    1    0    1    1    0]

Comment: Can you share the input values? We need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to check and fix the issue.

Comment: i added a dropbox link, thank you

Comment: Please share a reduced dataset as part of your post. Links may become broken in the future. Additionally, some of these sites, like Dropbox and Google drive, will share personal information (for example, your Dropbox link includes your entire name).

Comment: Please format your data in a way that we can easily use it. You also don't need to give every data point. The question would probably still be valid if you downsampled it. Please see an explanation of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your plot omits the massive spike at x ~ 25, y = 1290. I assume you want to ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine. As shown in StackOverflow Gaussian fit questions (over, and over, and over again), add good bounds and an initial guess.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, Bounds


def curve_f(x: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float, e: float, f: float, g: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return (
        1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi) *
        (
            + a/c * np.exp(-0.5*((x - b)/c)**2)
            + d/f * np.exp(-0.5*((x - e)/f)**2)
        )
        + g
    )


y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -110, 1290, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, -1, -2, -1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, -3, 5,
              5, 7, 3, 10, 3, 11, 10, 4, 16, 13, 32, 23, 21, 23, 37, 42, 42, 43, 56, 62, 41, 56, 71, 59, 61, 84, 82, 76, 73, 78, 73, 69, 84, 85, 74, 65, 75, 59, 74, 73, 76, 74,
              60, 95, 63, 91, 85, 82, 73, 72, 76, 82, 71, 85, 71, 60, 53, 71, 84, 95, 83, 50, 88, 63, 76, 68, 81, 73, 80, 60, 89, 78, 76, 86, 73, 99, 91, 94, 104, 98, 114, 117,
              110, 122, 104, 106, 121, 135, 130, 161, 146, 133, 172, 145, 186, 202, 222, 216, 205, 200, 234, 219, 231, 265, 269, 266, 296, 286, 304, 303, 325, 319, 381, 328,
              362, 370, 339, 360, 423, 405, 368, 400, 411, 416, 448, 454, 453, 468, 480, 427, 433, 490, 471, 505, 500, 442, 483, 482, 462, 436, 457, 483, 435, 431, 432, 416,
              410, 438, 402, 422, 387, 403, 366, 371, 369, 339, 341, 306, 327, 331, 310, 296, 277, 259, 268, 228, 214, 225, 234, 204, 208, 205, 205, 176, 168, 190, 192, 142,
              161, 126, 107, 122, 112, 86, 107, 92, 90, 89, 78, 82, 59, 69, 67, 57, 34, 42, 46, 44, 35, 36, 37, 29, 28, 29, 25, 20, 20, 18, 20, 17, 8, 22, 12, 9, 9, 7, 13, 8,
              11, 5, 5, 14, 5, 3, 6, 4, 6, 9, 2, 5, 5, 2, 4, 5, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 6, -1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 4, 3, 1,
              2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, -1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 2, 3, 0, -1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1,
              1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, -1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])

# Ignore massive spike at beginning
y = y[30:]

x = np.arange(len(y))
x0 = [5000, 50, 25, 25000, 150, 25, 0]
popt, *_ = curve_fit(
    f=curve_f,
    xdata=x,
    ydata=y,
    p0=x0,
    bounds=Bounds(
        lb=[1e-2,   0, 1e-2, 1e-2,   0, 1e-2, -1000],
        ub=[1e+6, 400, 1000, 1e+6, 400, 1000,  1000],
    )
)
print(popt)

plt.scatter(x, y, label='experiment', marker='+', color='green')
plt.plot(x, curve_f(x, *x0), label='guess')
plt.plot(x, curve_f(x, *popt), label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: fit]

Or not in PDF form:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, Bounds


def curve_f(x: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float, e: float, f: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return (
        + a * np.exp(-0.5*((x - b)/c)**2)
        + d * np.exp(-0.5*((x - e)/f)**2)
    )


y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -110, 1290, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, -1, -2, -1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, -3, 5,
              5, 7, 3, 10, 3, 11, 10, 4, 16, 13, 32, 23, 21, 23, 37, 42, 42, 43, 56, 62, 41, 56, 71, 59, 61, 84, 82, 76, 73, 78, 73, 69, 84, 85, 74, 65, 75, 59, 74, 73, 76, 74,
              60, 95, 63, 91, 85, 82, 73, 72, 76, 82, 71, 85, 71, 60, 53, 71, 84, 95, 83, 50, 88, 63, 76, 68, 81, 73, 80, 60, 89, 78, 76, 86, 73, 99, 91, 94, 104, 98, 114, 117,
              110, 122, 104, 106, 121, 135, 130, 161, 146, 133, 172, 145, 186, 202, 222, 216, 205, 200, 234, 219, 231, 265, 269, 266, 296, 286, 304, 303, 325, 319, 381, 328,
              362, 370, 339, 360, 423, 405, 368, 400, 411, 416, 448, 454, 453, 468, 480, 427, 433, 490, 471, 505, 500, 442, 483, 482, 462, 436, 457, 483, 435, 431, 432, 416,
              410, 438, 402, 422, 387, 403, 366, 371, 369, 339, 341, 306, 327, 331, 310, 296, 277, 259, 268, 228, 214, 225, 234, 204, 208, 205, 205, 176, 168, 190, 192, 142,
              161, 126, 107, 122, 112, 86, 107, 92, 90, 89, 78, 82, 59, 69, 67, 57, 34, 42, 46, 44, 35, 36, 37, 29, 28, 29, 25, 20, 20, 18, 20, 17, 8, 22, 12, 9, 9, 7, 13, 8,
              11, 5, 5, 14, 5, 3, 6, 4, 6, 9, 2, 5, 5, 2, 4, 5, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 6, -1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 4, 3, 1,
              2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, -1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 2, 3, 0, -1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1,
              1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, -1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])

# Ignore massive spike at beginning
y = y[30:]

x = np.arange(len(y))
x0 = [80, 50, 20, 500, 150, 30]
popt, *_ = curve_fit(
    f=curve_f,
    xdata=x,
    ydata=y,
    p0=x0,
    bounds=Bounds(
        lb=[1e-2,   0, 1e-2, 1e-2,   0, 1e-2],
        ub=[1e+6, 400, 1000, 1e+6, 400, 1000],
    )
)
print(popt)

plt.scatter(x, y, label='experiment', marker='+', color='green')
plt.plot(x, curve_f(x, *x0), label='guess')
plt.plot(x, curve_f(x, *popt), label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```